# Is there any tab specific unique id safari browser

Tags: safari-extension

i want to store tab specific values in a array. i want to store tab unique id as key. is there any unique id for safari browser tab.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you figure out an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a unique identifier, but could you use the URL of the tab? Off the top of my head:

```
tab = event.target.browserWindow.activeTab.url
```